# Extracting data from JSONP in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, highcharts

So, I'm using the API by a company called MarkitOnDemand for getting stock data.

Server Side:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getStockData' : function(tickerSymbol) {
    check(tickerSymbol, String);
    this.unblock();
    url = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/InteractiveChart/jsonp?parameters=%7B%22Normalized%22%3Afalse%2C%22NumberOfDays%22%3A365%2C%22DataPeriod%22%3A%22Day%22%2C%22Elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22Symbol%22%3A%22" + tickerSymbol + "%22%2C%22Type%22%3A%22price%22%2C%22Params%22%3A%5B%22c%22%5D%7D%5D%7D"
    var response = HTTP.call( 'GET', url, {
      params: {
        "callback" : "lookup"
      },
      headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
      }
    });
    // console.log(response);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log('Success');
      return(response.content)
    }
  }
});
```

Client Side:

```
Template.LookupChartTemplate.rendered = function () {
  stockData = Meteor.call("getStockData", stockname.Symbol, function(error, results){
    console.log(results);
  });
}
```

The client side console.log(results) results in something like the following:

```
lookup({"Labels":null,"Positions":[0,0.004,0.008,0.012,0.016,0.02,0.024,0.028,0.032,0.036,0.04,0.043,0.047,0.051,0.055,0.059,0.063,0.067,0.071,0.075,0.079,0.083,0.087,0.091,0.099,0.103,0.107,0.111,0.115,0.119,0.123,0.126,0.13,0.134,0.138,0.142,0.146,0.15,0.154,0.158,0.162,0.166,0.17,0.174,0.178,0.182,0.186,0.19,0.194,0.198,0.202,0.206,0.209,0.213,0.217,0.221,0.225,0.229,0.233,0.241,0.245,0.249,0.253,0.257,0.261,0.265,0.269,0.273,0.277,0.281,0.285,0.289,0.292,0.296,0.3,0.304,0.308,0.312,0.316,0.32,0.324,0.328,......
```

Now the question:

How do I get the data out of the callback result I get?

Expected End Result:

I want to get all the key/value pairs from the jsonp response and assign them to various variables (so that I can pass them to highcharts for making charts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONP is a dirty hack to work around the same origin policy in browsers. You aren't using a browser, so you don't need it.

Change the URL from `/jsonp` to `/json` and the API will give you plain JSON back.

You can parse that with `JSON.parse`

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with this idea for now, while I get a better understanding of the callback. Thank you.

Comment: Lovely. I didn't thought such thing _not using browser_.

Answer (score 2):

Now as you can see you got the `JSONP` with a function named `lookup(...data...)`, you have to call/create this function to extract the data:

```
var lbls, pos;

function lookup(data){
    lbls = data.Labels;
    pos = data.Positions;
}
```

Now in the highcharts you can use `lbls` and `pos` varialbles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, let's say I return the whole jsonp object (named response in this case) I get from the server to the client, how do I access the function named lookup on the client side?